# How we can create `notify()` method in object?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I was asked this question in an interview.

```
How you can create your own notify() method ?
```

I told this is a `native` method and can't be overridden.

But she was not happy with the answer.

Can someone explain?

Comment: I think there is a hint in **creating your own**, it need not neccessarilly be called `notify()`.

Comment: Native methods can be overridden. `notify()` cannot be overriden because it is `final`.

Comment: @skiwi please elaborate.

Comment: @Thinker I interpret the question as creating *some notify()-equivalent method*, so you could also call it `myOwnNotify()` and provide your own implementation.

Comment: Maybe she was talking about implementing the Observer pattern on your own ...

Comment: Was the interviewer asking how would you implement the wait/notify functionality in the JVM level, or how would you implement a similar functionality with Java code?

Comment: I would ask the *interviewer* for the clarification that is so obviously needed. If it's just a question about overriding final methods it's trivial. If it's a question about implementing notifications, it's redundant, as it's already done for you. Not much of a question IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the interviewer wanted a java implementation of something equivalent to wait/notify mechanism, without making use of Object.wait() and Object.notify() directly.

For example, any of the following high level synchronization mechanisms can be used to simulate wait/notify:

- BlockingQueue implementations
- SynchronousQueue
- CountDownLatch
- CyclicBarrier
- Futures

Note, however, that the semantics may be a little different than wait/notify. Unlike standard wait/notify, with blocking queues for example you have the advantage that a "notification" is captured by the waiter thread even if it's not waiting at the moment of the notification.

Following is a very simple implementation using SynchronousQueue:

```
public class WaitNotify {
  private final Object ITEM = new Object(); 
  private final SynchronousQueue<Object> q = new SynchronousQueue<Object>();

  public void myNotify() {
    q.offer(ITEM);
  }

  public void myWait() throws InterruptedException {
    q.take();    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the thread scheduler or thread manager (or whatever it is called in the JVM), you can implement the notify with a hash table which says which thread is waiting on which object's monitor. So I mean a hash table mapping object to thread. When notify is called on an object obj, your thread scheduler should get an event about this, then it would look up which threads are waiting on this particular object's monitor (i.e. on obj), and it would bring one of them back to runnable state. As others noted this looks similar to an observer pattern indeed. Not sure if that's a very good answer but it's the best that comes to my mind.